# TypeError: jQuery.sap is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sapui5

Hi i am using openui5 and `jquery.sheet.js` for excel type ui.

to use `jquery.sheet.js` we have to include `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`. 
If i use `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` openui5 throws error :
 **TypeError: jQuery.sap is undefined.**

Comment: You can try to use the [noJQuery-file](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f1dd0c6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for it which have same error...

Comment: hi @herrlock if i use noJquery openui5 events are not working for openui5 controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is fixed by first Bootstrapping the openui 5

```
 <script 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"            
            src="resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" >
    </script>
```

and then include **jquery-1.10.2.min.js**
i mean changing the order of script